Do I need a custom Oracle Dialect, as well as a custom DialectProvider just to make a Spring Boot Java Web application with an Oracle database?
I'm making a school project and it requires us to make some sort of a web application for and Oracle database. My team chose Spring Boot Java with Maven in an MVC style and I'm in charge of the backend. I started looking this up for it and I discovered JPA. Here is an example of a Model I wrote. Feel free to point out any mistake, I'm here to learn to code properly.
package hu.projekt.webshop.Model;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CEG")
public class Ceg {

    @Id
    @Column("NEV")
    private String nev;
    @Column("ORSZAG")
    private String orszag;
    @Column("ALAPITVA")
    private Integer alapitva;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "gyarto")
    private List<Termek> termekek;

    public Ceg() {
    }

    public Ceg(String nev, String orszag, Integer alapitva) {
        this.nev = nev;
        this.orszag = orszag;
        this.alapitva = alapitva;
    }

    public String getNev() {
        return nev;
    }

    public void setNev(String nev) {
        this.nev = nev;
    }

    public String getOrszag() {
        return orszag;
    }

    public void setOrszag(String orszag) {
        this.orszag = orszag;
    }

    public Integer getAlapitva() {
        return alapitva;
    }

    public void setAlapitva(Integer alapitva) {
        this.alapitva = alapitva;
    }

    public List<Termek> getTermekek() {
        return termekek;
    }

    public void setTermekek(List<Termek> termekek) {
        this.termekek = termekek;
    }

}

This is the basic Repository for it.
package hu.projekt.webshop.Repository;

import hu.projekt.webshop.Model.Ceg;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface CegRepository extends JpaRepository<Ceg, String> {

    @Override
    <S extends Ceg> S save(S entity);

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Ceg c WHERE c.nev = ?1")
    Ceg findByNev(String nev);

    @Override
    List<Ceg> findAll();

    @Query("DELETE FROM Ceg c WHERE c.nev = ?1")
    boolean deleteByNev(String nev);

}

And the basic Service.
package hu.projekt.webshop.Service;

import hu.projekt.webshop.Model.Ceg;
import hu.projekt.webshop.Repository.CegRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class CegService {

    private final CegRepository cegRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CegService(CegRepository cegRepository) {
        this.cegRepository = cegRepository;
    }

    public boolean cegMentes(String nev, String orszag, Integer alapitva) {
        return cegRepository.save(new Ceg(nev, orszag, alapitva)) != null;
    }

    public Ceg cegKereses(String nev) {
        return cegRepository.findByNev(nev);
    }

    public List<Ceg> cegLista() {
        return cegRepository.findAll();
    }

    public boolean cegTorles(String nev) {
        return cegRepository.deleteByNev(nev);
    }

}

Both of the are pretty basic, more methods will be implemented later if needed.
Here is my application.properties. The Oracle server is in the school, so I have to use PuTTY for an SSH Tunnel and Port Forwarding.
spring.application.name=Webshop

# Database connection properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:15210:orania2
spring.datasource.username=my_username
spring.datasource.password=my_password
oracle.ucp.minPoolSize=5
oracle.ucp.maxPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

# Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

I have writen a custom DataSource class, not sure if I really need to though.
package hu.projekt.webshop.Utilities;

import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource;
import oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${oracle.ucp.minPoolSize}")
    private String minPoolSize;
    @Value("${oracle.ucp.maxPoolSize}")
    private String maxPoolSize;
    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name:oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Bean(name = "OracleUniversalConnectionPool")
    @Primary
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        PoolDataSource pds = null;
        try {
            pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();

            pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName(driverClassName);
            pds.setURL(url);
            pds.setUser(username);
            pds.setPassword(password);
            pds.setMinPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(minPoolSize));
            pds.setInitialPoolSize(10);
            pds.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.parseInt(maxPoolSize));

        } catch (SQLException ea) {
            System.err.println("Error connecting to the database: " + ea.getMessage());
        }

        return pds;
    }

}

My current problem is the Spring application fails as soon as I start it.
Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(java.sql.SQLException, String)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcIsolationDelegate.sqlExceptionHelper()" is null
I have looked up errors like this and came across the fact that Spring doesn't have a built in Oracle Dialect. It might be that or something else I completely missed.

The property on the Spring side is not "dialect" but "database-platform" :
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect


I added the line, but I got this error Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

May depends on your Hibernate version but in any case the available dialects are in that package "org.hibernate.dialect", so check the one for Oracle available there in the version you are using.
